# sql avg not returning expected result

Tags: sqlite

I'm running the following on my sqlite3 DB, but the result is not limited to the last 3 records. It is returning the average for all records.

```
SELECT AVG(time) FROM tbl_aa ORDER BY ID LIMIT 3
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a subquery to get the first 3 records and then calculate the average on them

```
select avg(time) from
(
   SELECT time
   FROM tbl_a 
   ORDER BY ID 
   LIMIT 3
) x
```

Answer (score 1):

Limit will restrict the number of results in your result set, however AVG is calculated on the entire set so will only return one row. Therefore the limit is redundant.